# Wordpress: filter custom post archive page with an specified taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive, custom-taxonomy

Hi i'm using this code for displaying list of my post in archive page:

```
<article class="item se <?php echo get_post_type(); ?>" id="post-<?php echo the_id(); ?>">

//post information

    </article>
```

How can I filter post list by taxonomy:
result: show only list of post that have the specified taxonomy in archive page

Answer (score 1):

you have two options.

1. the first: you can create a file named archive-taxonomyname.php
2. the second: create wordpress query: 
   `$args = array('tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy'      => 'nametaxonomie')));
   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );`